# Loop multi dimensional array to meet jQuery conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have this array:

```
var conditions = [];
    conditions [0] = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"];
    conditions [1] = ["5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
    conditions [2] = ["19", "20", "21", "22"]; 
    conditions [3] = ["13", "14", "15", "16"];
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the array so that when the weather.code value (retrieved using jQuery) meets the value in the array, the background colour will change accordingly. The if statement isn't complete, this is just an example to show you what I mean:

```
if(weather.code === **item in conditions[1] for example**) {
   $("#page").css({background: "#F7AC57"}, 1500);
} 
else {
   $('#page').css({background: "#000"}, 1500);
}
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this would be appreciated. I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: You are looking for array prototype indexOf() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Array/indexOf) function:

```
if(conditions[1].indexOf(weather.code) != -1) {
   $("#page").css({background: "#F7AC57"}, 1500);
} 
else {
   $('#page').css({background: "#000"}, 1500);
}
```

Use the same for others:

```
if(conditions[0].indexOf(weather.code) != -1) {
   $("#page").css({background: "#F7AC57"}, 1500);
} 
else {
   $('#page').css({background: "#000"}, 1500);
}
if(conditions[2].indexOf(weather.code) != -1) {
   $("#page").css({background: "#F7AC57"}, 1500);
} 
else {
   $('#page').css({background: "#000"}, 1500);
}
if(conditions[3].indexOf(weather.code) != -1) {
   $("#page").css({background: "#F7AC57"}, 1500);
} 
else {
   $('#page').css({background: "#000"}, 1500);
}
```

I recommend you using a `switch` statement for this.